# EmEditorで複数のマクロを連続で順番に実行させる連続マクロは可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

複数の工程を一発でマクロでやりたい場合に保守性の観点からマクロのファイルを工程に分けて保存しておき、複数の工程を並べて組み合わせを並べ替えて実行させることは可能でしょうか？

たとえば、

実行順序を指定する

マクロ行程1.jsee
マクロ行程2.jsee
マクロ行程3.jsee
マクロ行程3.jsee

このように順番を並べて実行する方法です。

ひとつのマクロにしてやりますと毎回結合したマクロをひとつファイルとして作らないといけなくなり、順番や行程を変えたいとき再度作成の手間がかかってます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

以下のマクロを実行します。

```
#include "マクロ行程1.jsee"
#include "マクロ行程2.jsee"
#include "マクロ行程3.jsee"
#include "マクロ行程3.jsee"
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。